# OSX 10.1.4 Compressor produces 19GB file Finder shows as Zero Bytes

Tags: macos, finder, refresh

When compressing video from Final Cut Pro X using Compressor (4.2.2) the files produced are large, 19GB or more. The process takes about 7 hours. I usually let it run overnight. (Yes, 7 hours, Intel I7 4.3 GHZ 8 cores).
In the morning or even later in the day the file produced shows as "Zero Bytes". Even when right clicking and choosing "Show Info" it still shows as "Zero Bytes"

Opening a new Finder window, or changing the sort order in Finder does nothing. I have a third party utility called "Find Any File". It finds it and it will show the files true size. Then, switching to Finder usually will then show the true size, but not always.

How do you "Refresh" Finder???

Comment: Check your title. You said 10.1.4.  Did you mean 10.11.4? 10.10.4?

Comment: Does the compressed file actually work? Did it corrupt or fail at some point in the process?

Comment: My script, posted in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216399/finder-does-not-update/216404#216404 will work up to Yosemite, but not El Capitan. El Cap needs the Finder to be killed to refresh.